# Does requesting libraries only use more memory when starting or overall?

Tags: node.js

Let's say I require a module like `request` instead of the `http` module, and `request` uses a little bit more memory, would it only use more memory at the start or each time the script does something (even if it doesn't use either `require` or `http`)?

To be more exact, if the script monitors a chat for messages, reading every message, checking it for commands and only using `require` or `http` when it needs to (rarely) would it use extra memory each timee it's reading a message, or only when it makes an HTTP request?

I'm used to PHP so this is a bit new for me.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by *"each time the script does something"*, could you be more exact please?

But as far as I understand your question: There's no need to require `request` everytime you want to use it.

```
const request = require('request');

chat.on('message', msg => {
    // Do your request stuff
});
```

is the same as

```
chat.on('message', msg => {
    const request = require('request');
    // Do your request stuff
});
```

but much more efficient.